# Firefox Extension content script with css and background images

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon

I'm currently finishing a firefox extension which uses some content scripts. One of them appends some html/css in the current tab with JQuery:

```
var content = ''; //a lot of html
$('body').append(content);
```

It's worked well, but the background image in the css won't work:

```
var content = '<style type="text/css">#elem{background:url("http://example.com/image.png") no-repeat center center;}</style>';
content += '<div id="elem"></div>';
```

The div was here and the style was applied to it, but no background image at all. I've tried with a simple img element it doesn't work, either.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style` tags belong in the `head`, not the `body`.

I also found that I had to add `height` and `width` properties to the selector for `"elem"` in order for the thing to be visible.

Comment: No you can add style in body without any problem. The css here is not the "real" css have height/width.

Comment: Finally you're right, css with background-image or fontface won't work in Firefox. Adding the css to head solve my problem :)